# Why is my search bar not working (python, flask)?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to implement a basic search bar functionality to my site.

I will process the actual search on my database later but at the moment I am trying to just send the request, which will simply be a string from my search bar to my search route.

I have my search bar form:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="{{ url_for('search') }}">
  <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search!</button>
</form>
```

and my route

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    user_search = request.args['search']
    return render_template('results.html', search=user_search)
```

When I use my search bar I get the following error:

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'search'
```

I do not understand where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the request does not have "search" args. This can fix your problem:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="{{ url_for('search') }}">
  <input class="form-control" name="search" type="search" placeholder="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search!</button>
</form>
```

I added name "search" in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `name` attribute on the field to be able to access it as `request.args['search']`.

```
<input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" name="search">
```

Comment: OP will still get `KeyError` when they try to use `GET` no? maybe `request.args.get('search')` will be better